# Constraint layout pushing Views off-screen on device but not AVD

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm working on an app for Android, and have been using a Constraint Layout inside a LinearLayout to get some TextViews to be side by side, each taking up half of the screen.

The below screenshot is from an AVD (Pixel 2, but looks the same on other AVDs of different scale / DPI), and everything is centered properly. The red background behind the score label is just for contrast.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGOGs.jpg

However, when pushed to an actual device (in this case a Samsung Note 9), the 'score' TextView seems to grow and push everything to the right, and off the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoVdJ.jpg

I've tried making it a packed chain, played with horizontal bias from 0.0 to 1.0, changing the font size to a very small one (just for testing), removing the space View, and it all turns out the same on the device.

I'm not new to Java but I'm very new to Android development, so I apologize if this is something simple that I've missed (I could not find anything quite the same in my search)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreDisplay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#BFCF0000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="@string/score"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/space1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/timerDisplay"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/scoreDisplay"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#BF000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="@string/time_left"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add somewhere whole layout xml code? It is hard to discover issue with just that sample

Comment: here is the full layout: https://pastebin.com/qpNGrzQi

Comment: Do you make any change to the layout programmatically?

Comment: the only changes made programmatically are updating the textViews with setText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a few hours fighting with this and finding no reasonable conclusion as to why it would not work properly on one specific device (a physical Note 9, nobody else I know has one) when it worked fine on every single other device, both physical, and AVD, I ended up scrapping the constraintLayout and instead nested a LinearLayout. Not as good for performance, but is working as intended/needed.

ADDENDUM:
I found the root of the problem. It's with the Note 9 itself (though I haven't seen this issue in other apps on the device, maybe its a specific ConstraintLayout issue? I don't use many apps at all on my phone..) My Note 9 was in WQHD+ mode (2960x1440) which caused all sorts of weird stuff when using layouts with ConstraintLayout (2.0.0-beta2) with UI elements being pushed off the screen. Switched back to FHD+ (2220x1080) as came from the factory and everything started working again. Not sure if the issue is on Samsung's end (maybe device is zoomed in at the FQHD+ resolution so the actual edge of the 'screen' is off the actual screen(?) or the issue somehow lies within the current release of ConstraintLayout itself.

So, as a note to self. My original code posted worked on everything but the Samsung Galaxy Note 9 in WQHD+ resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently don't have real device but try without the `Space`, just replace your `ConstraintLayout` with this one:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreDisplay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#BFCF0000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="@string/score"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timerDisplay"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#BF000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="3"
            android:text="@string/time_left"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/scoreDisplay"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I replaced my constraintLayout section with yours, unfortunately the result is the same:https://imgur.com/a/5j14vJ7

Comment: I had that issue once but forgot how I solve it. Can you remove this line of code from both of your `Textviews`: `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"`

Comment: I just tried that, both with and without the extra space view; same result as before. As a side note, I reached out to my mother (Galaxy J3) and my sister (Galaxy S8+) and neither of them are having this issue - I had them pull directly from the Play Store (which has my original code listed above in it)